# JSOUP get div content from div's with same name

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I wish to parse webpage which has 2 div's with the same class.

Following is the part of the webpage i'm trying to parse:

```
<div class="bid-row rgray bmatch" id="m590574">
<div class="mtime">12:00</div>
<div class="mteams w240" data-original-title="" title="">
    <div class="team">Rayo Vallecano</div>
    <div class="team">Malaga CF</div>
</div>
<div class="modds w160">
    <div class="clear">
        <div class="blank"></div>
        <input class="bet" id="q43909084" type="button" value="2.35">
        <input class="bet" id="q43909085" type="button" value="3.30">
        <input class="bet" id="q43909086" type="button" value="3.15">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="minfo">
    <div class="stats" data-brid="7610448_1"></div>
    <div data-tvinfo="Sky Sports 4, Sport1 HU, LiG TV 3, Canal+ Liga, NTV Plus Futbol 2, TK Futbol 1 UA, Digi Sport 2 RO, CANAL9 DK, Sport Klub 1 SRB, SKY Sport Plus IT HD, Eleven HD" class="fleft tv"></div>
    <div class="mlive"></div>
    <div class="slider" data-mode="1" data-tid="36" data-cid="32">+50<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></div>
</div>
```

I am using JSOUP to parse it, here is how my code looks like right now:

```
     Elements hrefElements = doc.select("div.bmatch");
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // root elements
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc1 = docBuilder.newDocument();
    org.w3c.dom.Element rootElement = doc1.createElement("company");

    doc1.appendChild(rootElement);

     String[] mtime = new String[hrefElements.size()];

     String[] team = new String[hrefElements.size()];
     String[] tvinfo = new String[hrefElements.size()];

     for(int i=0;i<hrefElements.size();i++)
     {
         mtime[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByClass("mtime").text();
         team[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByClass("team").text();
         tvinfo[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByTag("div").attr("data-tvinfo");
     }
     for(int j=0;j<hrefElements.size();j++)
     {
         // staff elements
    org.w3c.dom.Element staff = doc1.createElement("Event");
    rootElement.appendChild(staff);

    // set attribute to staff element
    Attr attr = doc1.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue("1");
    staff.setAttributeNode(attr);
          org.w3c.dom.Element firstname = doc1.createElement("Time");
    firstname.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(mtime[j]));
    staff.appendChild(firstname);

    // lastname elements
    org.w3c.dom.Element lastname = doc1.createElement("Teams");
    lastname.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(team[j]));
    staff.appendChild(lastname);





    // nickname elements
    org.w3c.dom.Element nickname = doc1.createElement("TV");
    nickname.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(tvinfo[j]));
    staff.appendChild(nickname);


         System.out.println("Time: "+mtime[j]);
         System.out.println("Event: "+team[j]);
         System.out.println("TvInfo: "+tvinfo[j]);
     }
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc1);
             String nameGame =  jTextField3.getText();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("test.xml"));
            //StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(System.out);
 transformer.transform(source, result);
    // Output to console for testing
    // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    System.out.println("File saved!");

}
```

However, the output i get for that part of HTML is the following:

```
 <Event id="1">
        <Time>Today12:00</Time>
        <Teams>Rayo Vallecano Malaga CF</Teams>
        <TV>Sky Sports 4, Sport1 HU, LiG TV 3, Canal+ Liga, NTV Plus Futbol 2, TK Futbol 1 UA, Digi Sport 2 RO, CANAL9 DK, Sport Klub 1 SRB, SKY Sport Plus IT HD, Eleven HD</TV>
    </Event>
```

The final xml i'm trying to achieve should look something like this:

```
        <Event id="1">
        <Time>Today12:00</Time>
        <Team1>Rayo Vallecano</Team1>
        <Team2>Malaga CF</Team2>
        <TV>Sky Sports 4, Sport1 HU, LiG TV 3, Canal+ Liga, NTV Plus Futbol 2, TK Futbol 1 UA, Digi Sport 2 RO, CANAL9 DK, Sport Klub 1 SRB, SKY Sport Plus IT HD, Eleven HD</TV>
    </Event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByClass("team").text();` to get team names, it returns appended text of all macthing elemets. in this case `Rayo Vallecano Malaga CF` for teams `Rayo Vallecano` and `Malaga CF`.

Try this.

```
        Elements hrefElements = doc.select("div.bmatch");
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc1 = docBuilder.newDocument();
        org.w3c.dom.Element rootElement = doc1.createElement("company");
        doc1.appendChild(rootElement);


        for( int i = 0; i < hrefElements.size(); i++ ) 
        {
            // staff elements
            org.w3c.dom.Element staff = doc1.createElement("Event");
            rootElement.appendChild(staff);

            // set attribute to staff element
            Attr attr = doc1.createAttribute("id");
            attr.setValue("" + (i + 1));
            staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

            Element timeSection = hrefElements.get(i).select("div.mtime").first(); // one time section
            Element teamsSection = hrefElements.get(i).select("div.mteams").first(); // one team section
            Element infoSection = hrefElements.get(i).select("div.minfo").first(); // one info section

            String time = timeSection.text();
            Elements teams = teamsSection.select("div.team"); // many teams within team section
            String tvInfo = infoSection.select("div.tv").first().attr("data-tvinfo");

            // time element
            org.w3c.dom.Element timeElement = doc1.createElement("Time");
            timeElement.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(time));
            staff.appendChild(timeElement);
            System.out.println(timeElement.getTextContent());

            // teams
            for(int j = 0; j < teams.size(); j++) {
                org.w3c.dom.Element teamElement = doc1.createElement("Team" + (j + 1));
                teamElement.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(teams.get(j).text()));
                staff.appendChild(teamElement);
                System.out.println(teamElement.getTextContent());
            }

            // tv info
            org.w3c.dom.Element nickname = doc1.createElement("TV");
            nickname.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(tvInfo));
            staff.appendChild(nickname);
            System.out.println(nickname.getTextContent());
        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc1);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("test.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("File saved!");
```

Comment: Ty Sir, that was exactly wht i needed.